# Commerce Product Display or just Views Display of line items?

Tags: views, commerce

I will be presenting the products in one view and don't need the display nodes as they wont be seen.

Do I have to create display nodes for each product or can I just use views to display the line items in a table for example?

Is there any catch with doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't see products because the permission to see products is disabled by default.
Just enable it at `/admin/people/permissions`. E.g. enable `View any product of any type` if you want to permit users to see directly entities.

But also have a look at the module [Inline entity form](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/videos/commerce-module-tuesday/inline-entity-form). you can edit both node display and attached product entities in one form.

Comment: thanks for the comment but I don't want to show or hide the product displays. I want to know if I have to create the product displays at all or can I just use the products in a Views table?

Comment: ofcourse you can use only products entities. It's up to you

Comment: but the disadvantage of using products entities that you don't have page with full information of single product from the box

Comment: Can you clarify "you don't have page with full information of single product from the box"

Is there any other disadvantage to not having separate display pages for each product, reporting etc?

Comment: on my opinion there are no more disadvantages